# divisibility theorem proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I have found in a book the proof for the divisibility problem that says:

If $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b$ is not equal to zero, then there is a unique pair of integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a=qb+r$ and $0\leq r<|b|$

When the author wants to proof existence, he states the following: $q=-|ab|/b$ and $r=a+|b|$

I was wondering, how do the author came to the above mentioned equations; I have been trying to deduce them, but no luck at all.

Comment: There must be some typos here. This is all totally wrong. You could take $q=[a/b]$ if you allow the greatest integer function $[x]$.

Comment: No @TedShifrin, I have put it exactly as it appears on the book

Comment: I wonder what book has such egregious typos ...

Comment: This is the one to blame for @TedShifrin: http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Technology-Rowan-Garnier/dp/075030135X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1461020967&sr=8-1&keywords=discrete+mathematics+for+new+technology

Comment: Wow. Totally appalling. Presumably a later edition corrected this, but that's unconscionable. (I say this as an author of 4 textbooks, and I was mortified when the mildest of typos showed up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is wrong. If we consider $a=2$ and $b=1$ then we should get $q=2$ and $r=0$ since $2=2\cdot 1+0$ but the book's equations instead give $q=-2$ and $r=3$. Plugging those values into the division formula yields $$-2\cdot 1+3=1\neq 2$$ and anyways $r$ isn't less than $b$. In fact, if $a$ is positive, these equations would give $$r=a+|b|>|b|>r$$ which is a contradiction.

The real answer involves the greatest integer function, $[x]$. We say that $[x]$ is the largest integer smaller than or equal to $x$ (this corresponds to the idea of rounding down). The correct values are $q=[a/b]$ and $r=a-[a/b]\cdot b$.